# How to hide a parent component from a child component?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

When my Angular application gets bootstrapped it uses my AppComponent which I have defined as follows:

**AppComponent.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'rfq-app',
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styles: []
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Test';
}
```

**AppComponent.html:**

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="board">
            <div class="progressbar">
                <progress-bar></progress-bar>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I use the following routing definition defined in its own file:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'product/:code', component: ProductComponent  },
    { path: 'personal', component: PersonalComponent, canActivate: [WorkflowGuard] },
    { path: 'supplier', component: SupplierComponent, canActivate: [WorkflowGuard] },
    { path: 'summary', component: SummaryComponent, canActivate: [WorkflowGuard] },
    { path: 'products', component: ProductFilterComponent },
];
```

This has been working perfectly. I can navigate to the routes and the components will be loaded just as I want. However, when I added the last route:

```
{ path: 'products', component: ProductFilterComponent }
```

I do **not** want to show the `<progress-bar>` component used in `AppComponent.html` in this case. In fact, I only want to show the `<progress-bar>` when I navigate to one of the four first components (part of a multistep form), so that's `ProductComponent, PersonalComponent, SupplierComponent, SummaryComponent`.

For all other routes (there's only one other at the moment: `ProductFilterComponent`), I want to just show the component without the `<progress-bar>`.

In my `ProductFilterComponent` I have tried to do the following:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'product-filter',
    templateUrl: './productfilter.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./productfilter.component.css']
})
```

and in the css stylesheet I have added

```
.progressbar {
    display: none;
}
```

in order to hide the div containing the progress bar. If I do this directly from the browser dev tools, then it hides it, but it seems like I can't get this css applied from the `ProductFilterComponent`.

I'm launching the Angular application from my Asp net core backend by including it in a razor view:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/ClientApp/dist/inline.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="~/ClientApp/dist/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="~/ClientApp/dist/styles.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="~/ClientApp/dist/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="~/ClientApp/dist/main.bundle.js"></script>
}

<rfq-app></rfq-app>
```

---

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a quick easy way to hide the progress bar?
2. I feel like the design of my Angular application is not right. The progress bar sits on a too high level. But I'm unsure how to take it a level down so only some components make use of it. Should I change my design, if yes what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a simple service for this:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadingService {
    $loading: BehaviourSubject<boolean> = new BehaviourSubject(true);

    constructor(){}

    public startLoading(): void {
        this.$loading.next(true);
    }

    public stopLoading(): void {
        this.$loading.next(false);
    }
}
```

Provide and Inject this service and call `startLoading` and `stopLoading` whenever you want.

AppComponent

```
<div *ngIf="loadingService.$loading | async" class="progressbar">
    <progress-bar></progress-bar>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! But I get an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` in the console. What I did was to inject the service in AppComponent.ts and call `startLoading()` in its constructor. Similarily I injected it in my `ProductFilteringComponent` and call `stopLoading()` in my `ngOnInit()` method. Only in the latter case (ProductFiltering) do I get the error. Any idea why?

Comment: Not completly sure. Try putting it in a `setTimeout( () => {})`